"Breakpoint unverified" when trying to debug OCaml
I'm setting up Neovim as an IDE for the first time and I got stuck trying to setup debugging in OCaml. I have general OCaml environment setup in the system, I can build and run projects. LSP and none-ls in Neovim are configured and working fine.
I created a new Hello World project with dune init proj hello and added (modes byte exe) to the dune file. Simple code I used for testing:
let s = "Hello, OCaml debug"
let () = print_endline s

I built it with dune build, main.bc is created as expected and it does print the line on dune exec hello.
I set the breakpoint on any or both lines with <leader>b, which causes B markers to appear next to the line. Then I try to launch main.bc in debugger with <F5> and the B breakpoint marker in Neovim window changes to R. No DAP UI appears, just a quick screen glitch. In dap.log it only says:
[ INFO ] 2024-08-13T00:52:39Z+0200 ] ...ster/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:911 ]  "Breakpoint unverified" {
  id = 1,
  verified = false
}
[ INFO ] 2024-08-13T00:52:39Z+0200 ] ...ster/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1447 ] "Process closed"    290638

Manual debugging outside of Neovim works fine. Not sure if and how can I test ocamlearlybird itself.
❯ ocamldebug _build/default/bin/main.bc
        OCaml Debugger version 5.2.0

(ocd) r
Loading program... done.
Hello, OCaml debug
Time: 32
Program exit.
(ocd)

I pretty much copied https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/lua/kickstart/plugins/debug.lua and added setup for ocamlearlybird as per nvim-dap documentation. My complete plugin configuration for debug is:
return {
    "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
    dependencies = {
        -- Creates a beautiful debugger UI
        "rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui",

        -- Required dependency for nvim-dap-ui
        "nvim-neotest/nvim-nio",

        -- Installs the debug adapters for you
        -- 'williamboman/mason.nvim',
        "jay-babu/mason-nvim-dap.nvim",
                "hackwaly/ocamlearlybird",
    },
    keys = function(_, keys)
        local dap = require("dap")
        local dapui = require("dapui")

        return {
            -- Basic debugging keymaps, feel free to change to your liking!
            { "<F5>", dap.continue, desc = "Debug: Start/Continue" },
            { "<F1>", dap.step_into, desc = "Debug: Step Into" },
            { "<F2>", dap.step_over, desc = "Debug: Step Over" },
            { "<F3>", dap.step_out, desc = "Debug: Step Out" },
            { "<leader>b", dap.toggle_breakpoint, desc = "Debug: Toggle Breakpoint" },
            {
                "<leader>B",
                function()
                    dap.set_breakpoint(vim.fn.input("Breakpoint condition: "))
                end,
                desc = "Debug: Set Breakpoint",
            },
            -- Toggle to see last session result. Without this, you can't see session output in case of unhandled exception.
            { "<F7>", dapui.toggle, desc = "Debug: See last session result." },
            unpack(keys),
        }
    end,
    config = function()
        local dap = require("dap")
        local dapui = require("dapui")

        require("mason-nvim-dap").setup({
            -- Makes a best effort to setup the various debuggers with
            -- reasonable debug configurations
            automatic_installation = true,

            -- You can provide additional configuration to the handlers,
            -- see mason-nvim-dap README for more information
            handlers = {},
        })

        -- Dap UI setup
        -- For more information, see |:help nvim-dap-ui|
        dapui.setup({
            -- Set icons to characters that are more likely to work in every terminal.
            --    Feel free to remove or use ones that you like more! :)
            --    Don't feel like these are good choices.
            icons = { expanded = "▾", collapsed = "▸", current_frame = "*" },
            controls = {
                icons = {
                    pause = "⏸",
                    play = "▶",
                    step_into = "⏎",
                    step_over = "⏭",
                    step_out = "⏮",
                    step_back = "b",
                    run_last = "▶▶",
                    terminate = "⏹",
                    disconnect = "⏏",
                },
            },
        })

        dap.listeners.after.event_initialized["dapui_config"] = dapui.open
        dap.listeners.before.event_terminated["dapui_config"] = dapui.close
        dap.listeners.before.event_exited["dapui_config"] = dapui.close

                dap.adapters.ocamlearlybird = {
                        type = 'executable',
                        command = 'ocamlearlybird',
                        args = { 'debug' }
                }

                dap.configurations.ocaml = {
                        {
                                name = 'OCaml Debug test.bc',
                                type = 'ocamlearlybird',
                                request = 'launch',
                                program = '${workspaceFolder}/_build/default/test/test.bc',
                        },
                        {
                                name = 'OCaml Debug main.bc',
                                type = 'ocamlearlybird',
                                request = 'launch',
                                program = '${workspaceFolder}/_build/default/bin/main.bc',
                        },
                }

    end,
}

What am I missing here?


It would really help answerers to have the complete source of the code you debug and the exact sequence of steps you took (go to this line, run this command, etc.). Please [edit] to clarify.

You may also be able to get help from the plugin community (say, by discussing at the plugin's issue tracker or browsing its documentation)

I've edited to provide more details. I will also ask the same question on OCaml's forum.

Okay, I found this webpage which describes how does ocamldebug actually work and now I see it counts events and not lines like I expected coming from more popular languages. So the problem is actually of PEBKAC variety, not in Neovim or OCaml tooling, and I simply need to learn some OCaml.
For example in the piece of code below if I put a breakpoint on second print_endline it will do the first print, but placing a breakpoint on first print will just make it rejected.
let dosomething a =
        String.concat "What? " a

let () =
        print_endline (dosomething ["test"; "bleh"]);;
        print_endline "Huh";;


The configuration that does launch OCaml debugging correctly, may require some cleaning up:
return {
    "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
    dependencies = {
        -- Creates a beautiful debugger UI
        "rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui",

        -- Required dependency for nvim-dap-ui
        "nvim-neotest/nvim-nio",

        -- Installs the debug adapters for you
        -- 'williamboman/mason.nvim',
        "jay-babu/mason-nvim-dap.nvim",
        "hackwaly/ocamlearlybird",
    },
    keys = function(_, keys)
        local dap = require("dap")
        local dapui = require("dapui")

        return {
            -- Basic debugging keymaps, feel free to change to your liking!
            { "<F5>", dap.continue, desc = "Debug: Start/Continue" },
            { "<F1>", dap.step_into, desc = "Debug: Step Into" },
            { "<F2>", dap.step_over, desc = "Debug: Step Over" },
            { "<F3>", dap.step_out, desc = "Debug: Step Out" },
            { "<leader>b", dap.toggle_breakpoint, desc = "Debug: Toggle Breakpoint" },
            {
                "<leader>B",
                function()
                    dap.set_breakpoint(vim.fn.input("Breakpoint condition: "))
                end,
                desc = "Debug: Set Breakpoint",
            },
            -- Toggle to see last session result. Without this, you can't see session output in case of unhandled exception.
            { "<F7>", dapui.toggle, desc = "Debug: See last session result." },
            unpack(keys),
        }
    end,
    config = function()
        local dap = require("dap")
        local dapui = require("dapui")

        require("mason-nvim-dap").setup({
            -- Makes a best effort to setup the various debuggers with
            -- reasonable debug configurations
            automatic_installation = true,

            -- You can provide additional configuration to the handlers,
            -- see mason-nvim-dap README for more information
            handlers = {},
        })

        -- Dap UI setup
        -- For more information, see |:help nvim-dap-ui|
        dapui.setup({
            -- Set icons to characters that are more likely to work in every terminal.
            --    Feel free to remove or use ones that you like more! :)
            --    Don't feel like these are good choices.
            icons = { expanded = "▾", collapsed = "▸", current_frame = "*" },
            controls = {
                icons = {
                    pause = "⏸",
                    play = "▶",
                    step_into = "⏎",
                    step_over = "⏭",
                    step_out = "⏮",
                    step_back = "b",
                    run_last = "▶▶",
                    terminate = "⏹",
                    disconnect = "⏏",
                },
            },
        })

        -- dap.listeners.after.event_initialized["dapui_config"] = dapui.open
        -- dap.listeners.before.event_terminated["dapui_config"] = dapui.close
        -- dap.listeners.before.event_exited["dapui_config"] = dapui.close

        dap.adapters.ocamlearlybird = {
            type = "executable",
            command = "ocamlearlybird",
            args = { "debug" },
        }

        dap.configurations.ocaml = {
            {
                type = "ocamlearlybird",
                request = "launch",
                name = "Launch debug test",
                -- console = "integratedTerminal",
                -- program = "_build/default/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.bc",
                program = "_build/default/bin/main.bc",
                cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
                stopOnEntry = true,
                yieldSteps = 4096,
                onlyDebugGlob = "<${workspaceFolder}/**/*>",
            },
        }
    end,
}


